# get value after last slash (/)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get background image by doing

```
$('#item').css('background-image').
```

but the result is `url('www.example.com/something/123.png')`

How can get get only the 123 value? I can't use string position because the value of the img name doesn't' necessary is 3 characters.

Comment: @Amit farker how to not to use split as i have multiple slash!

Comment: you can split on `/` and take the last element and split on `.` and take the first element.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `lastIndexOf` and `substring`:

```
var uri= $('#item').css('background-image');
var lastslashindex = uri.lastIndexOf('/');
var result= uri.substring(lastslashindex  + 1).replace(".png","");
```

or using `.split()` and `.pop()`

```
var uri= $('#item').css('background-image');
var result=uri.split("/").pop().replace(".png","");
```

Comment: @aviatewong: that would be lastslashindex